# Read list of servers for user?

Tags: linux, shell-script, read

How can i read list of server entered by user & save it into variable ?

Example:

```
Please enter list of server:
(user will enter following:)
abc
def
ghi
END

$echo $variable

abc
def
ghi
```

I want it to be running in shell script.If i use following in shell script:

```
read -d '' x <<-EOF
```

It is giving me an error :

```
line 2: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Please suggest how can I incorporate it in shell script ?

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net/ for syntax error issues

Comment: I am not sure how to use "read" in shell script and what options to use with read command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
servers=()                     # declare an empty array
# allow empty input or the string "END" to terminate the loop
while IFS= read -r server && [[ -n $server && $server != "END" ]]; do
    servers+=( "$server" )     # append to the array
done
declare -p servers             # display the array
```

This also allows the user to manually type entries or to redirect from a file.

Comment: I have used following code. Thank you for your help. echo " Enter List of server & type END at the end of file:"
touch serverlist
while read name
do
if [ "$name" = "END" ]; then
break
else
echo "$name" >> serverlist
fi
done

Answer (score 0):

It's very uncommon for a script or program to ask a user to interactively give a list of items (effectively acting like a poor man's text editor with no undo).

It is a lot more common for scripts or programs to read lists of items from a prepared file:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r item; do
    printf 'The item given by the user is %s\n' "$item"
done
```

This script would then be used as

```
$ ./script.sh <myfile
```

where `myfile` would be a text file with lines that the script would read and do something with.

Running this script *without* an input file would be possible.  Input would then have to be typed manually.  To signal the end of this manual input, one would press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

Comment: I want user to enter list of servers which i will put into file & use it for PSSH.

Comment: Why not let the _user_ put the list of servers into a file with an editor, and then read that file later with the script that calls PSSH?

Comment: @SumeetPanse See previous comment (I forgot to tag you). Also, that would allow the user to re-use a list without having to re-type it every time.